# redirect_uri_mismatch error when enabling server side access to Google API

Tags: python, android, oauth

I have an Android app with a Python server. I need the server to have access to the users' emails constantly, so I'm following this guide:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

```
def google_api(auth_token):
    # If this request does not have X-Requested-With header, this could be a CSRF
    #if not request.headers.get('X-Requested-With'):
        #abort(403)

    # Set path to the Web application client_secret_*.json file you downloaded from the
    # Google API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'secret.json'

    # Exchange auth code for access token, refresh token, and ID token
    credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
        CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 'profile', 'email'],
        auth_token)

    print credentials
    return credentials.id_token
```

I get the following error:

> FlowExchangeError: redirect_uri_mismatch

Here is the secret.json:

```
{"web":{"client_id":"REDACTED",
"project_id":"REDACTED",
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"REDACTED",
"redirect_uris":["http://localhost:8080/"],
"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:8080"]}}
```

I've also tried using `http://my_actual_domain.com:5000/` for the `redirect_uris` and it still returns the same error.

I don't understand what `redirect_uris` is supposed to be or mean? It's not mentioned in the guide I link at the top

Answer (score 0):

Redirect uri is something which you give it when you created OAuth Client ID. The one you used in the application should match the one you gave while requesting the Client ID.

Please make sure this configured properly.

[image]